# How to customize color and scale of y axis in each multiple plot using plot.zoo?

Tags: r, time-series, panel, axis, zoo

This a reproducible example of my data

```
dat<-data.frame(
prec<-rnorm(650,mean=300),
temp<-rnorm(650,mean = 22),
pet<-rnorm(650,mean = 79),
bal<-rnorm(650,mean = 225))
colnames(dat)<-c("prec","temp","pet","bal")
    
dat<-ts(dat,start = c(1965,1),frequency = 12)
#splines
fit1<-smooth.spline(time(dat),dat[,1],df=25)
fit2<-smooth.spline(time(dat),dat[,2],df=25)
fit3<-smooth.spline(time(dat),dat[,3],df=25)
fit4<-smooth.spline(time(dat),dat[,4],df=25)
    
dat2 <- cbind(dat, fitted(fit1), fitted(fit2), fitted(fit3), fitted(fit4))
plot.zoo(window(dat2, start = 1965), xlab = "", screen = 1:4, 
col = c(1:4, 1, 2, 3, 4),yax.flip = TRUE, bty="n")
```

How can I modify the color and the scale of the y axes in each plot to match the same color of the time series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `dat2` which contains both the series and the smooth splines, use `window` to start it at 1965, specify in `screen=` that the the columns be in panels 1:4 (it will recycle for the last 4 columns) and specify that the last 4 columns be black, i.e. 1, or modify colors to suit.

```
dat2 <- cbind(dat, fitted(fit1), fitted(fit2), fitted(fit3), fitted(fit4))
plot.zoo(window(dat2, start = 1965), xlab = "", screen = 1:4, 
  col = c(1:4, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

[image: screenshot]

Regarding the comment, to me it seems easier to read if the ticks, labels and axes are black but if you want to do that anyways  use the `mfrow=` graphical parameter with a `for` loop and specify `col.axis` and `col.lab` in the `plot.zoo` call:

```
nc <- ncol(dat)
cols <- 1:nc  # specify desired colors
opar <- par(mfrow = c(nc, 1), oma = c(6, 0, 5, 0), mar = c(0, 5.1, 0, 2.1))
for(i in 1:nc) {
  dat1965 <- window(dat[, i], start = 1965)
  plot(as.zoo(dat1965), col = cols[i], ylab = colnames(dat)[i], col.axis = cols[i],
    col.lab = cols[i])
  fit <- smooth.spline(time(dat1965), dat1965, df = 25)
  lines(cbind(dat1965, fitted(fit))[, 2])  # coerce fitted() to ts
}
par(opar)
mtext("4 plots", line = -2, font = 2, outer = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks very much @G. Grothendieck. Final question. Do you know how I may change the ylab axis color (labels, ticks, and values) for each panel, so they will have the same color to their corresponding time series. e.g. data.temp, its values 20,22,24 and yticks must be red to match its time series color. So far I have tried col.axis="red" but it changes for all the panels

Comment: See addition at end.

Comment: Thanks again for your response. But I would like to use plot.zoo as it is easier to manipulate the plot. So may you please take a look at the ammended code (I edited the post). How can one modify the color of the axis and the scale of the y axis in each plot in this case?

Comment: I have simplified the code slightly but conditional col.axis and col.lab is not supported nor is this straight forward in any of the graphics systems.  The straight forward way to do this regardless of which system you use is to create each plot separately and then put them together as we have done.  Suggest you use the code provided or if you really want this in plot.zoo submit a patch to support vector col.axis and col.lab (scalar col.axis and col.lab are supported and we use those in the code above).

Comment: I understand now why I could not modify it. I will accept your suggestions and work with the provided code. Thanks very much for your time and help, you have saved me plenty of time. Kind regards